# Unhide Datagrid column in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I am developing a WPF application.There is a `datagrid` in my Application i have created a context menu to hide and unhide column header of the datagrid while assigning the itemsource of datagrid to an IEnumerable collection.

```
 this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = objref.Result;


                grid_data = objref.Result;
                cxMenu = new ContextMenu();

                foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn item in dataGrid1.Columns)
                {
                    menuItem = new MenuItem();
                    menuItem.Header = item.Header;
                    menuItem.IsChecked = true;
                    cxMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                    menuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem_Click);
                    menuItem.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem_Checked);
                    menuItem.Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem_Unchecked);
                }
```

Everythjing working fine. when i uncheck the columns are successfully remobved but when i again check the `MenuItem` of my `ContextMenu` it is not added.

Handler of my check event is as follows.

```
 void menuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = objref.Result;// Again assgining the whole set to itemssource
        List<string> menuList = new List<string>();
        menuList.Clear();



    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in cxMenu.Items)
    {
        if (menuItem.IsChecked == false)
        {
            menuList.Add(menuItem.Header.ToString());
        }
    }

        Functionsclass objref = new Functionsclass();


        foreach (string menuItem in menuList)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Header.ToString() == menuItem)
                {
                    dataGrid1.Columns.Remove(column);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But my column is not added when i check again. Please help me on this.

Update 2:

```
 void menuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        if (item.IsChecked)
        {
            item.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            item.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    void menuItem_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Header.ToString().Contains(item.Header.ToString()))
            {
                dataGrid1.Columns.Remove(column);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Uncheck handler.

Comment: when you are Unchecking  the column name you are removing the column name from grid,you have code for that but when you check that back ,you need to add that column back to grid,where is that part of code.

Comment: For that only i have added the entire column again and removed the columns which is unchecked in context menu..LL update that code too

Comment: Both Checked and Unchecked you are removing the column???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide/show columns, I don't think Removing/Adding columns is the right approach. I suggest you make use of the `Visibility` property of the column. set it to `Visibility.Collapsed` to hide it, then `Visibility.Visible` to make it visible again.

```
column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Column is hidden

column.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Column is Visible
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just changed my checked and Unchecked event handlers like below. Now its working fine..:)

```
//Unchecked handler

 void menuItem_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
        {
           if (column.Header.ToString().Contains(item.Header.ToString()))
            {
               column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                break;
            }


        }
    }
```

// Checked handler

```
    void menuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;

        List<string> menuList = new List<string>();
        menuList.Clear();
         foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
        {
           if (column.Header.ToString().Contains(item.Header.ToString()))
            {
               column.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                break;
            }


        }

    }
```